# plotting while looping with a continuously generated data: @not showing plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make two figures plot using matplot in python, the data is generated in a MCU simulation with two sensors and transmitted through UDP connection between Cisco's Packet Tracer and PyCharm's python server, then sent to a second MCU that I completed the coding for no need to spend time on MCU2 codes.

The need to plot while there is an infinite loop running to acquire transmitted data that are being used to plot with without being blocked by `plt.show()`, which is resolved by:

```
# in plot init
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
# in loop
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

what i face is that my plot is empty, and not showing the data Iam feeding it to.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X13rV.png)

the Server code:

```
# Libraries that will be used
import socket
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time

# initializing ip,ports for mcu1,2 and a boolean statement to signal mcu2
print("running")
UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 4444
UDP_PORT2 = 5555
ventelate = False
plotAction = False

# create our figure and subplots
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

# Adding labels to subplots is a little different
ax1.set_title('tempertioer')
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylabel('%')
ax2.set_title('Carbon')
ax2.set_xlabel('time')
ax2.set_ylabel('CO')

# Subplots_adjust change the space between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

def animate(i):
    ###plotting initalizaton x,y axis
    x_val = []
    x_val2 = []
    y_val = []
    y_val2 = []
    index = count()
    index2 = count()

    # plot values appenders
    x_val.append(next(index))
    x_val2.append(next(index2))
    y_val.append(y1)
    y_val2.append(y2)

    # griding the plots
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(x_val2, y_val2)

    plt.ion()
    plt.show()

# socket defining
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))  # binds ip,port ot sock(upove in line 38+39)

# loop
while True:

    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % data)
    dataString = str(data.decode('utf-8'))  # decoding received data
    seperatedData = dataString.split(",")  # arranging data into array

    y1 = seperatedData[0]
    y2 = seperatedData[1]

    # plot action
    if plotAction:
        ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=100)
        plotAction = False

    # Draw all the plots!
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)

    # comparing values to either signal MCU2 or not
    if int(seperatedData[0]) >= 20 or int(seperatedData[1]) == 1023:
        ventelate = True;
        print("sending open")
    else:
        ventelate = False;
        print("sending close")

    if ventelate:
        MESSAGE = b"1"  # encoding to utf-8 / byte condotion

        print(" open")
        sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                              socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
        sock2.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT2))
    else:
        MESSAGE = b"0"

        print(" close")
        sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                              socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
        sock2.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT2))
```

the code for MCU:

```
from realudp import *
from time import *
from gpio import *
from realudp import *

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 4444

def onUDPReceive(ip, port, data):
    print("received from "
        + ip + ":" + str(port) + ":" + data);

def main():
    
    sensor1= (((analogRead(A0) - 0) * (100 - -100)) / (1023 - 0)) + -100;
    sensor2= digitalRead(0);
    
    
    MESSAGE =  sensor1, sensor2
    
    
    
    print("UDP target IP: %s" % IP)
    print("UDP target port: %s" % PORT)
    print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)
    
    
    udp = RealUDPSocket()
    udp.begin(4444)
    
    udp.send(IP,PORT,MESSAGE)
    udp.stop()
    
    
    socket = RealUDPSocket()
    socket.onReceive(onUDPReceive)
    print(socket.begin(4444))
    count = 0   
    while True:
        sensor1= (((analogRead(A0) - 0) * (100 - -100)) / (1023 - 0)) + -100;
        sensor2= digitalRead(0);
    
        MESSAGE =  sensor1, sensor2
        
        count += 1
        socket.send(IP, PORT, MESSAGE," "+ str(count))
        
        delay(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `plt.show()` blocks the execution of the rest of the code. It seems that you are trying to create an animation: try https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Comment: @YuliaV is that true even with `ion` ? i thought if using ion it would continue past `plt.show()`

Comment: @JoranBeasley no idea, I have never used `ion`. `plt.show(block=False)` should do the job if blocking is not needed.

Comment: @YuliaV 
```.ion``` does the job of executing without blocking.
but it's not drawing